# Can you get rid of the title as "THIEF"?

Tags: zelda-links-awakening

There is a shop in the starting area on the island of Koholint, and if you are fast enough to dance around the shopkeeper, you can steal from him. Once you steal from him, though, your title in the game changes to "THIEF".

[Here is a video of what I am talking about.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9KHTqt4unso)

Is there any way to change your title back to your name without reverting to a different past save or starting over?

[image: THIEF, the new title.]

Comment: No AFAIK.  You're branded a thief for the rest of your life or your save game gets replaced or expires, whichever comes first.  You could probably cheat using a cheat device to alter your name somehow.

Comment: @Jeff your correct, this happens to be my favorite zelda game and one of my favorite games of all time. It's been years since I played it but my memory on this particular aspect remains clear. Go ahead and post an answer.

Comment: @JeffMercado Post it as an answer.

Comment: @Foxtrot: That's fine, Moonlighter has posted it. I generally do "comment answers" here when I'm only really speculating and can't really back up my answer. Though it's just as good to receive confirmation.

Comment: @JeffMercado just wanted to make sure, as I like to give credit to the first answer. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no way to change it back. Only doing some romhacking, which will still be complicated.