# Where do I get the Bow?

Tags: zelda-links-awakening

I was in Catfish's Maw, and noticed a few places with bunches of arrows floating in the air (so you can grab them using the Roc's Feather). Problem is, I have no use for them because I don't have a Bow.

Did I miss the Bow somewhere? Where can I find it? It would be a useful weapon to have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The Bow & Arrow can be found in the shop mid-way through the game for
>   a whopping 980 Rupees. A lot of money, but the monopoly you'll have to
>   do for this item is worth it.

I usually just stole this item as saving for it always became a pain... Its in the main shop in the first city you start in.  Keep in mind, if you steal something, your name will forever be changed to [THIEF!](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/52208/can-you-get-rid-of-the-title-as-thief)

Comment: IIRC, you also have to have purchased the Shovel for the Bow to be available for purchase.

Comment: Also remember to not go back into the shop after thieving. The shopkeeper is a rather murderous fellow.

Answer (score 3):

You can save up for it pretty quickly using the mini-game with the crane in the shop below the one that sells you the bow.

You can net 40 rupees per play if you get both rupee prizes.

Here's a video that shows how to win each time

Also note after you buy the bow, IMMEDIATELY SAVE AND QUIT, and you can keep almost all of your rupees! Although doing this will change your name to THIEF, the shop keeper won't be angry.